# How to rotate log files based on time rather than size in Log4j?

Tags: java, log4j

I use Log4j with the `RollingFileAppender` to create a log rotation based on size.

How can I configure it to log to each file for a certain amount of *time* before rotating?

For example, so that each log file contains one hour of logs, rotating at the top of each hour?

I configure Log4j programatically in Java using a `Properties` object (as opposed to a `log4j.properties` file)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You probably want to use a [DailyRollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html). To roll them hourly, for example, you'd use a DatePattern of `'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH`. For a log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.appender.myAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
...
```

Or for your programmatic configuration:

```
DailyRollingFileAppender appender = new DailyRollingFileAppender();
appender.setDatePattern("'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH");

Logger root = Logger.getRootLogger();
root.addAppender(appender);
```

Unfortunately, using a DailyRollingFileAppender means that you can't limit the file size - this could be problematic if you have tons of logs in the given rolled period.

Comment: But aren't there potential threading issues? I've heard of cases where it fails to roll over if other threads are logging.

Comment: DailyRollingFileAppender has been observed to exhibit synchronization issues and data loss. The log4j extras companion includes alternatives which should be considered for new deployments and which are discussed in the documentation for org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender.

Answer (score 4):

Additionally,

```
log4j.appender.myAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
**log4j.appender.myAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH**
```

The following list shows all the date patterns which have defined by log4j,

```
Minutely  '.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm application.log.2013-02-28-13-54
Hourly '.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH application.log.2013-02-28-13
Half-daily '.'yyyy-MM-dd-a application.log.2013-02-28-AM app.log.2013-02-28-PM
Daily '.'yyyy-MM-dd application.log.2013-02-28
Weekly '.'yyyy-ww application.log.2013-07 app.log.2013-08 
Monthly '.'yyyy-MM application.log.2013-01 app.log.2013-02
```

Answer (score 3):

The other thing to be careful of with any rolling file appender is to make sure only one JVM access a particular log file at a time.  This is because log4j caches the log file size for performance reasons, and your 'rolling' will get wonky if multiple JVMs access the same files.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "vm"?

Comment: I mean the java virtual machine.   Each instance of the 'java' executable.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [DailyRollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html).

In particular, setting its 'datePattern' property to `'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH` would cause file to rotate every hour.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [DailyRollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html). Despite its misleading name it can be configured in a to run at configurable time periods up to minutes.