# How can I make Log4j to create new log file everyday?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Here is my Log4j.properties file.
Which save everything in log4j-application.log file.
Is there any way to create new file everyday or create new 
log file every time i run my project??

Thanks in advance

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}          %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=D:\\log4j-application.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}    %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Quite a few questions handle this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132433/one-logfile-per-run-with-log4j, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618527/create-new-log-file-daily-using-log4j ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is called "log rotation". Looks like your specific question about creating new log daily is already answered [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1711441/767632).